# Find files created over a certain number of seconds ago then copy it

Tags: macos, bash, find, rsync, seconds

So I'm trying to make a script that watches for files that haven't been modified for at least 10 seconds then to execute an rsync on the file. My original line was this:

```
find "/Volumes/Media/" -type f -size +2G -cmin +1 -cmin -60 -exec rsync -aq --update {} /Volumes/LocalMedia/ \;
```

But that does 1 minute, which is too long. So far I've gotten down to this:

```
find "/Volumes/Media/" -type f -size +2G -exec bash -c 'echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -f%c "{}") ))' \;
```

which gives me the output of the files in the directory by seconds. But I seem to be having trouble evaluating that and performing the aforementioned rsync. This is macosx so it's bsd find not GNUfind.

Any thoughts/help would be lovely.

Thanks,
 -N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using `mtime`:

```
find "/Volumes/Media/" -type f -size +2G -mtime +10s -exec rsync -aq --update {} /Volumes/LocalMedia/ \;
```

Using `-mtime +10s` would return to `find` only files older than `10 seconds`

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked, I had tried mmin and cmin with +10s but that didn't work, didn't know to try mtime, you rock.